# Use Will_paginate with hash keys in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, will-paginate

I have a hash where the keys are objects, and the values arrays of another objects. In a view I want to show a list with these objects in keys and paginate them. But will_paginate doesn't seems to work with hashes...

Here's my controller:

```
@hash = Hash.new

articles_pending_review.each do |a|
    duplicates_ids = JSON.parse(a.properties)["duplicates"].split(',').collect! {|n| n.to_i}

    duplicates_ids.each do |d|
        article = Article.unscoped.find(d)
        @hash[article] = [] if !@hash[article]

        @hash[article].push(a) unless @hash[article].include?(a)
    end
end
```

And my view:

```
%ul.articles_list
    - @hash.each do |article_key, duplicates_array|
        %li
            %p= article_key.name

            %ul.article_duplicates_list
                - duplicates_array.each do |d|
                    %li= d.name
```

I've found similar questions but I don't know how to apply them in my case. Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use custom pagination, e.g:

```
@paginated_articles = WillPaginate::Collection.create(current_page, per_page, total) do |pager|
  pager.replace @hash.keys
end
```

See [here](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/array.rb) for more info.